# Data cannot be read from REDIS

Tags: java, linux, redis, kylin

My java project can read and write data on other linux systems normally, the newly deployed production environment is the Kirin Linux system under the arm architecture, when running the web system on it, only one hour before the start can read and write normally, the subsequent can only write can not read the data, restart the java project can read the data, beginners please advise thank you

My Redis version is 4.0.11 and I tried to upgrade to 5.0.11 either. After modifying the application configuration file, there is no recovery, and the following is the configuration information of Redis in the application：
lettuce:
  shutdown-timeout: 100
  pool:
   max-active: 8
   max-idle: 8
   max-wait: -1
   min-idle: 0